# use two different link style the same page

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, pseudo-class

[image][image]ı want to use below, but there is an error.problem..

```
a.tarz7:link,a:visited,a:active
{
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
/* 
background-color:#6699FF;
*/
background-image:url(images/bgnisan2012/bg_rect_blue.gif);
width:130px;
text-align:center;
padding:1px;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:13px;
}
a.tarz7:visited
{
}

a.tarz7:hover
{
background-image:url(images/bgnisan2012/qbgblue.gif);
color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

AND..

```
a.buton_stil1{
    background:#3366CC;
    padding:5px 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    font:bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}


a.buton_stil1{
    background:#3366CC;
    padding:2px 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    font:bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

a.buton_stil1{
    background:#3366CC;
    padding:2px 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    font:bold 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 4px #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
}


a.buton_stil1:hover{
   /*  eski stil
   background-color:#3333FF;

    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 
    0,1, 0.25);
    */
box-shadow: 1px 3px 4px #000;
background-image:url(images/bgnisan2012/qbgblue.gif);
```

### on my top div,I use: buton_stil1

example :

```
<td align="center">
<a href="dun.php" class="buton_stil1" > Dün&nbsp; </a>
</td>
```

### on my content div, ı use a.tarz7

example :

```
<td>  
<a class="tarz7"  href="sorularim.php" > >>> </a>    
</td>
```

now, there i no problem on a.tarz7, but top buttons have problem with buton_stil1.
when ı press the buttons they are growing. like a.tarz7.

---

examle :
  Dün

### when ı click this link, link changing "tarz"

ı find a way, to seperate the effect of two link pseudo class. but there isnt.
eventually, will  ı delete one of them ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It was hard reading your code but I guess the problem is this

```
a.tarz7:link,a:visited,a:active
```

You must have meant this

```
a.tarz7:link,a.tarz7:visited,a.tarz7:active
```

Comment: sory.

you know thats are link kodes.
and all of them is RUNNING. but on different page.

if ı write not only "a.tarz7" but also "a.buton_stil1" in the same page.
and ı use them. there is an error.

because in the code

tarz7 ->display:block;  and  width:130px;

error is that : 
<a href="dun.php" class="buton_stil1" > Dün&nbsp; </a>

when ı click this link, link changing "tarz".

Comment: When you write `a:visited,a:active` it applies that style to ALL visited and active links on the page. Make the change Ashwin Singh suggested.

Comment: how?
I gave a diiferent name to them.

Comment: No you didn't. You only gave a class name with `:link`, you didn't give a class name with `:visited` or `:active`. Each selector is unrelated, starting the line with `a.tar7:link` doesn't mean that the rest of the selectors are just for `.tar7`.

Comment: hımm ohhh my bad times, so much empty working..
thanks. ı realise the my mistake.